# Git commit times are incorrect, will this cause any issues in the future?

Tags: git, gitlab

During testing one of our time sensitive features, we have forwarded our clock on our computer and made commits.

Some commits are a few months in the future and changes are already updated on our gitlab. Will this cause any issues in the future?

[image: multiple commits are 2 months in the future]

Image description:

- Today is 12 April
- Multiple commits are made on 6 April
- Multiple commits are 'made' on 8 June (2 months in the future)

Comment: _Will this cause any issues in the future?_ -- (we don't know unless the future is here) from the perspective of which tool? `git` does not really care about commit dates (both authors and committers) per se (not sure if future dates ever can affect merging and cause conflicts; I believe they can't). GitLab may be or not sensitive to future dates (but I still believe the GitLab dev team is fully aware of git future date support and they I believe took that into account for specific cases). I guess you have to observe and see what might go wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I think I am going to play it safe and migrate all the changes to a new branch with the correct dates to avoid any potential (if any) issues. Then I'll close this MR and delete the branch. The 2 affected branches are quite small.

Comment: _Will this cause any issues in the future?_ It seems to me it is causing issues right now: the commit dates are wrong.

Comment: We test for it for example in [spec/lib/gitlab/git/branch_spec.rb](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blame/v14.9.3-ee/spec/lib/gitlab/git/branch_spec.rb#L100-132).

Minor display problems have occurred: [gitlab-foss#18913](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/18913) & [gitlab-foss#3634](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/3634), for example.

[Bug reports](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/contributing/issue_workflow.html#issue-tracker-guidelines) for newly discovered issues are welcome